# How to show the results from leaflet-knn on the map

Tags: leaflet

I want to show the result as markers for the leaflet-knn on the map,i don't know how.
When i used `console.log(nearest)`,it gives me `[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]`
I tried `geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(nearest ).addTo(mymap);`,i got error `Bounds are not valid`
here is my code:

```
var gj = L.geoJson(data);
var nearest = leafletKnn(gj).nearestLayer(L.latLng(125.813,8.71772),100); 
geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(nearest).addTo(mymap);
mymap.fitBounds(geojsonLayer.getBounds());
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is not working? What is the result you're getting versus the expected result? What is the value of `nearest`?

Comment: I want to show the results as markers...i don't know how.when i used `console.log(nearest)`,it gives me `[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object] `..... i tried `geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(nearest ).addTo(mymap);` ...and i got error `Bounds are not valid`.

Comment: Please edit your original question, and rephrase it to include this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your geoJson is a collection of points, the markers are in the result:

```
nearest[i].layer
```

To show the results, you just have to add them to the map.

```
for(i=0; i<nearest.length; i++) {
  map.addLayer(nearest[i].layer);
}
```

Consider the original leaflet-knn example forked to show this: https://yafred.github.io/leaflet-knn/ (https://github.com/yafred/leaflet-knn/tree/gh-pages)

Comment: Yes they are all points...thanks for your reply it works but i need to add all the results not only one

Comment: nearest is an array. Just loop on it

Comment: Thanks alot it works :)...it seems that i have a problem in leaflet-knn itself as `nearest` returns all the points not only the nearest ones.

Comment: Are you aware the 2nd argument of leafletKnn() is the maximum number of location you want in return. You have put 100, that's a lot

Comment: I thought it was the distance(in meters) not the maximum number..how can i make it use specific distance?

Comment: i edited it to be `var nearest = leafletKnn(gj).nearest(L.latLng(125.818,8.81738),6,500000);
`..can you tell me how leaflet-knn works with distance?..i mean does it make buffer with distance i added and then get what inside it or how exactly it uses the distance?

Comment: Sorry, I did not dive into the source code. I just used the sample and the readme to answer.